# Multiple Instances of RCP, Adding MPerspective/MPart to a Dialog using E4

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I'm trying to achieve a couple of functionalities for my e4 rcp.

1. Create multiple instances of rcp, using a menu option in the rcp;

   > Eg: In eclipse IDE there is a menu option to achieve this,  `Window -> New Window`, creates another instance of the existing IDE.  I'm trying to achieve similar functionality for my rcp using e4.
2. Adding a perspective(`MPartStack`/`MPart`) to a dialog UI. 
   Is it possible to add a perspective to a Dialog 
   ( I could make a dialog as a modal, using `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL`, but I'm not sure if we can add / how to add a `Mperspective`, `MPart`, `MPartStack` to a dialog )

Can you please give me some pointers on how to achieve these functionalities?

Comment: You can't put parts in to a normal dialog. Eclipse Luna added dialogs to the application model but there is very little info on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks Greg. How about the 1st query, creating multiple instances of rcp, can we achieve it using E4 ?

Answer (score 1):

For new window look at the `EModelService` `cloneElement` and `cloneSnippet` methods to duplicate existing UI elements or to create a new copy of a pre-defined snippet from the application model.

Comment: thanks again, your 2 mins ahead, i just hit the below link, http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=458055/.